# If Tag(s) field is in a Profile that is used for Batch Update it shows no results - and removes all existing Tags when updated

Tags: tags

I can add Tags field to a Profile

I can then use that Profile for bulk updates

The Tags field shows as empty on the screen (and hence is easily ignored/overlooked)

Upon save ALL tags are removed from all those Contacts.

Sadness ensues and it rains a lot and your favourite team is kicked out of the FIFA World Cup.

If the Tags field is not safe to be used on Profiles used via Batch Updates then

- should we prevent Profiles that have the Tag field from being available via Batch Update or
- should the field show the actual Tags, so it just 'saves' them
- something else?

Whatever the solution, the current situation destroys data and needs a fix

Comment: Ouch.  The 'something else' could be to make it work!

Comment: This is indeed a major PITA. Slightly different point: I'd love to be able to use the bulk update screen to be able to quickly edit the tags for a group of records. The fact that the Tags field doesn't display, and therefore doesn't let me set tags for a given record, is to say the least disappointing. Plus 1 for either getting it to work properly, or disallow it. The current state of play is dangerous.